# How to validate multidimensional arrays with Codeigniter and Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, codeigniter, validation, multidimensional-array

Hi I need to validate a multidimensional form like this

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge span5 req" id="contact_first_name" name="hotel[<?=$id?>][contact_first_name]" value="<?= set_value('hotel[contact_first_name]') ?>">
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge span5 req" id="contact_last_name" name="hotel[<?=$id?>][contact_last_name]" value="<?= set_value('hotel[contact_last_name]') ?>">
```

I don't know the dimensions of the final array because the inputs are added dynamically via jquery.

I'm using Codeigniter Form_Validation for the server-side and via JQuery with the JQuery Validator for the client-side.

This is my form_validation rules

```
$config['add_hotel'] = array(
array(
    'field' => 'hotel[][hotel_name]', 
    'label' => 'Hotel Name', 
    'rules' => 'required'
    ),    
array(
    'field' => 'hotel[][contact_first_name]', 
    'label' => 'First Name', 
    'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
array(
    'field' => 'hotel[][contact_last_name]', 
    'label' => 'Last Name', 
    'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
```

and this is how i'm doing it via jquery validator

```
$("#add_hotel").validate({
rules: {
    "hotel[][hotel_name]": "required"

  /*  errorElement: "div",
    wrapper: "div"*/
},
messages: {
   "hotel[][hotel_name]": "Please enter the Association Name"
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

Don't know how to validate each `Hotel[]` input with its own id, or maybe there is another way to defining the inputs that can be simpler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posted array

```
$hotel = $this->input->post('hotel');
if(!empty($hotel))
{
    // Loop through hotels and add the validation
    foreach($hotel as $id => $data)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotel[' . $id . '][contact_first_name]', 'First name', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotel[' . $id . '][contact_last_name]', 'Last name', 'required|trim');
    }
}
```

Default rules that apply all the time

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // Errors
}
else
{
    // Success
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that do the trick for the CI Form_validation. Now i have to validate it by the JQuery Validator plugin, but don't know the way to create a var index inside the validation

Comment: is it possible to avoid the loop and set the validation rules in the config/form_validation.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has a very scrict way of handling the validation rules for inputs that are named as arrays, it will only validate if the field name is exactly the same, so the rule

```
array(
    'field' => 'hotel[][hotel_name]', 
    'label' => 'Hotel Name', 
    'rules' => 'required'
    ),
```

would only work if the field was actually named hotel[][hotel_name].
Since that is not the name of the field(the actual name is something like hotel[1][hotel_name]), it will not be validated by Codeigniter.

You can generate the config array dinamically, but i think you are better off writing your own validation rules for those fields separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
   is not working i am trying to like this
     in api data 
     {
      "fullname":"4545",
    "family_detail": [
       {
        "relation_id":""
      },
      {
        "relation_id":"11"
       }]
    }

   in controller 
   $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

   if ($this->form_validation->run('signup') == FALSE)
    {
     //error
    }else{
      // success
    } 
     in my config file
     $config = array(
   'signup' => array(   
    array(
     'field' => 'fullname',
     'label' => 'Full Name',
    'rules' => 'required'
      ),
     array(
    'field' => 'family_detail[][relation_id]',
    'label' => 'relation_id',
    'rules' => 'required'
     ),
     )
```