# how can i validate a multi dimentional array in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have a form with dynamic fields that result in a multidimensional array format, 
like this:

```
name="cart[1][qty]"
name="cart[2][qty]"
name="cart[3][qty]"
...
```

I use this rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cart[][qty]','number','is_natural');
```

but it fails to validate. If i change the rule to :

```
$this->form_validation>set_rules('cart[1][qty]','number','is_natural');
```

it just validates the first field, rather than all of the fields.

I would like to prevent from inserting the decimal numbers in this form.

How can I validate it in Codeigniter using `form_validation`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "Using Arrays as Field Names" section of the form validation might help you. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#using-arrays-as-field-names

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464001/how-to-validate-multidimensional-arrays-with-codeigniter-and-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try example below using foreach loop

```
$cart = $this->input->post('cart');

if(!empty($cart)) {

foreach($cart as $number => $data) {
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cart[' . $number . '][qty]', 'Number', 'is_natural');

}

}
```